# How to evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} (x^2\cdot\int_{0}^x e^{t^3-x^3} dt)$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(x^2\cdot\int_{0}^x e^{t^3-x^3} dt\right)$$

I am fairly new to calculus, and I have never encountered integrals with variables in the integration limits. How can such an integral be evaluated? Or does the trick to solving the question lie in evaluating the expression outside the integral along with the integral itself?

I am interested in knowing which areas of calculus can be applied in solving this question, and if there are any relevant resources explaining these topics.

Edit (modified question): The limit that x approaches is supposed to be infinity, not zero.

Comment: Notice that the bounds of the integral go from $0$ to $0$ when the limit is applied. The integral is made to look scary, but this is a very simple question when you apply the limit directly.

Comment: the Limit should be zero

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the answers say it's $\frac13$

Comment: It is just a matter of estimating 

$$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^3-x^3}\,dt = \int_{0}^{x} e^{(x-t)^3-x^3}\,dt =\int_{0}^{x}\exp\left(-3x^2 t+3xt^2-t^3\right)\,dt$$
with decent accuracy. By enforcing the substitution $t=\frac{z}{x^2}$, $dt=\frac{1}{x^2}\,dz$ we get that the original limit equals
$$ \lim_{x\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{x^3}e^{-3t}\exp\left(\frac{3t^2}{x^3}-\frac{t^3}{x^6}\right)\,dt $$
and by he dominated convergence Theorem we get that this limit equals
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-3t}\,dt = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**

That integral might not be elementary, but its derivative with respect to $x$ is. Can write the expression as $$ \frac{\int_0^x e^{t^3}}{e^{x^3}/x^2}$$ and apply L'Hospital. To do the derivative of the top you can use the FTC.